# on'guildMemberAdd' has stopped working. DiscordJs V.12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I haven't changed anything in the code. At last week on('guildMemberAdd') work.
But today it has stopped working. Help, please!

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member =>{
  console.log('1')
    try {
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get(requireNew('./data/config.json').memberAddChannel)
      const avatar = new Discord.MessageAttachment(member.user.displayAvatarURL());
      const img = new Discord.MessageAttachment(requireNew('./data/config.json').welcomeImg)
      if (!channel) return;
      channel.send(`<@${member.user.id}>, ${requireNew('./data/config.json').welcomeMsg}`,[avatar,img]);
      member.roles.add(requireNew('./data/config.json').baseRole);
      member.user.send("Here text");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Lioness100 Yes! That's it! Thank you very much! You saved my freelance order! :з

Comment: Haha, glad I could help.